# Set global variable from another package with setter Perl

Tags: perl, scope, arguments, global-variables

I am trying to set global variable in another package but unfortunatly it is set to the undef, nevertheless it is correct display argument variable in debugging mode but sets it undef.
Here is my code.

SuperFunc.pm

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package  SuperFunc;

my $global_x = 20;
my $global_y = 20;

sub set_x {
    my $new_x = shift;
    if($new_x) {
       $global_x = $new_x;
    }
}

sub set_y {
    my $new_y = shift;
    if($new_y) {
       $global_y = $new_y;
    }
}
```

And Main.pl

```
.......
SuperFunc::set_x($x);
SuperFunc::set_y($y);
.......
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be working fine.  I don't really understand the problem without more code.

Perhaps you're looking for http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/our.html ?

Script

```
use strict;
use lib "./lib";
use SuperFunc;

SuperFunc::log();
SuperFunc::set_x(1);
SuperFunc::set_y(2);
SuperFunc::log();
```

Module

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
package  SuperFunc;

my $global_x = 20;
my $global_y = 20;

sub set_x {
    my $new_x = shift;
    if($new_x) {
       $global_x = $new_x;
    }
}

sub set_y {
    my $new_y = shift;
    if($new_y) {
       $global_y = $new_y;
    }
}

sub log {
  print "$global_x\n$global_y";
}
```

Output

20

20

1

2